# Question about proof of sum of 2 continuous random variables - Joint Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am having trouble in understanding the proof of CDF & integral bounds of the sum of two independent, continuous random variables.

My lecture notes states:

> Fix z $\in R$, Then Z($\omega$) $\leq$ z means that X($\omega$) + Y($\omega$) $\leq$ z.

> Let $R_Z = \{(x,y): x + y < z\}$.Then $F_Z(z) = \int\int_{R_z}f(x,y) dxdy = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{z-x}_{-\infty} f(x,y)dxdy$

> Making the change if variable $y= v -x$ in the inner integral gives $F_Z(z) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{z}_{-\infty} f(x,v-x)dvdx = \int^{z}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x,v-x)dxdv$.

The question i have is the last line of the proof:
$$F_Z(z) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{z}_{-\infty} f(x,v-x)dvdx = \int^{z}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x,v-x)dxdv$$

How does making a substitution $ y = v - x $ allows us to swap around the integrals, and what does it mean geometrically?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Fubini/Tonelli Theorem?

Comment: @geetha290krm no i do not :(

Comment: Do you know any theorem on changing the order of integration?

Answer (score 0):

The substitution and swapping the interals are two separate actions.

1. The goal is to have a CDF in terms of a single variable $z$, and not $z-x$, that's why the substitution was made in the first place.
2. Provided the [appropriate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) conditions are met, you may simply change the order of integration, that's all that happens in the last line.

Regarding the conditions: Since $f\ge 0$ and it is integrable, the conditions for swapping the integrals are met, see the Section about the Fubini–Tonelli theorem.